# Return Result of a Regex::replace_all as str

Tags: regex, string, rust

I am trying to create a function that takes a `&str` as an input and gives a `&str` as an output. However I do not find any solution on how to comply with the borrow checker rules. It seems that the returned type is `Cow`, but I didn't found a way to convert it to a `&str`. Maybe I should keep this type?

Here is the function that I want to write:

```rust
fn replace_by_regex<'a>(text: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    let re = Regex::new(r"(PATTERN)").unwrap();
    let after = re.replace_all(&text, "").to_string().as_str();
    // println!("{}", after);
    after
}
```

But I get this error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/lib.rs:91:5
   |
89 |     let after = re.replace_all(&text, "").to_string().as_str();
   |                 ------------------------------------- temporary value created here
90 |     // println!("{}", after);
91 |     after
   |     ^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

But at the end of the day I aim to collect a modified `&str`.

Comment: Make sure you also [take a look at the `lazy_static` crate](https://crates.io/crates/regex#usage-avoid-compiling-the-same-regex-in-a-loop) when using the `regex` crate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about returning a String instead? Got it working in the [playground and included a test.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0f70d44b1b2be8108ce576693dac61e9)

```
use regex::Regex;

pub fn replace_by_regex(text: &str) -> String {
    let re = Regex::new(r"(PATTERN)").unwrap();
    let after = re.replace_all(text, "");
    println!("{}", after);

    after.into_owned()
}
```

Comment: Good idea, I will try to use strings on my program. Thank you

Comment: Please use into_owned instead. to_string will create a needless copy here.

Comment: Thanks, BurntSushi5. Changed it in the snippet and the playground.